# Docker: Error response from daemon: no such id:

Tags: docker, dockerfile

currently I try to launch docker image on deamon with `docker run -d ID` (after to launch this commande: `docker build -t toto .`)

But when I launch this commande: `docker exec -it ID bash`, I've got this error:

> Error response from daemon: no such id: toto

My Dockerfile look like that:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM debian:jessie

# Upgrade system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y --no-install-recommends

# Install TOR
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tor tor-geoipdb torsocks 

# INSTALL POLIPO
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y polipo

# INSTALL PYTHON
RUN apt-get install -y python2.7 python-pip python-dev build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev && apt-get clean

# INSTALL GIT
RUN apt-get install -y git-core

# INSTALL NANO
RUN apt-get install -y nano

# INSTALL SUPERVISOR
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# INSTALL SCRAPY and dependencies
RUN pip install lxml && pip install pyopenssl && pip install Scrapy   && pip install pyopenssl  && pip install beautifulsoup4  && pip install lxml   && pip install elasticsearch   && pip install simplejson  && pip install requests && pip install scrapy-crawlera && pip install avro && pip install stem

# INSTALL CURL
RUN apt-get install -y curl

# Default ORPort
EXPOSE 9001

# Default DirPort 
EXPOSE 9030

# Default SOCKS5 proxy port 
EXPOSE 9050

# Default ControlPort
EXPOSE 9051

# Default polipo Port
EXPOSE 8123

# Configure Tor and Polopo
RUN echo 'socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"'  >> /etc/polipo/config
RUN echo 'socksProxyType = socks5'  >> /etc/polipo/config
RUN echo 'diskCacheRoot = ""' >> /etc/polipo/config

RUN echo 'ORPort 9001' >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo 'ExitPolicy reject *:*' >> /etc/tor/torrc


ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:/scrapy

WORKDIR /scrapy
VOLUME ["/scrapy"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

In order to facilitate the usage of [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/), make sure you run your container with a name:

```
docker run -d --name aname.cont ...
```

I don't see an entrypoint or exec directove in the Dockerfile, so do mention what you want to run when using `docker run -d`

(I like to add '`.cont`' as a naming convention, to remember that it is a container name, not an image name)

Then a `docker exec aname.cont` bash should work.

Check that the container is still running with a docker ps -a

Answer (score 2):

When creating the container you should use the image name:

> docker run -d --name my_toto toto

You cannot impose an ID when creating it. It's Docker who assigns the ID.

Then connecting

> docker exec -it my_toto bash

---

A more quick way to do that is running directly

> docker run -d -it -name my_toto toto bash

The container will still existing after you exit.

Comment: That is indeed what I recommended in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I though you missed also the image name in the build command which is the main source of error  in the question.